# Set input type of a rest web service to Json

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm having a rest web service and i'm executing it through Rest Client in FF. Till now it was used as a post method now i've to change it's input type to JSON i.e now i'm sending json input to that ws but on rest client i'm getting

```
Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2013 07:52:50 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.30 PHP/5.3.6
```

Below is the ws new signature (I've added the Consume and Produce Line)

```
@Override
    @POST
    @Path("/addHouseHoldAccounts")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addHouseHoldAccounts(JSONObject jsonObject) {
....
....
}
```

on rest client i've set header `Content-Type application/json`

and below is the JSON input i'm trying to send

```
{
   "jsonObject":{
       "JsonId":"17fb00b6-dfa3-4cc6-b7ba-c54ecd429350",
   "JsonTypeOf":"JSonTest",
   "JsonType":"",
   "JsonTypetName":"JsonImplemented"
   }
}
```

can anyone point out my mistake or suggest me a solution for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the Request Header `"Accept"` as `"application/json"`

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you:

*WebService:*

```
        @POST
        @Path("/your_path")

        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        //Receive and send a json object
        public JSONObject receiveJSONObject(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
        {
               return json;
        }
```

*Client*

```
private void sendJSONObject() throws JSONException{

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        WebResource service = client.resource("*your_adress_and_path*");
        JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
        dados.put("Name", "John");
        dados.put("Age", "30");
        dados.put("City", "Tokyo");

        ClientResponse client_response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, data);

        System.out.println("Status: "+client_response.getStatus());

        client.destroy();

    }
```

I'm not sure, but I think you aren't setting the content type as json. This code worked for me.